# Java ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException

Tags: grpc, dagger, grpc-java

I have a requirement where we want to only build the ManagedChannel once & reuse it every time the stub makes a rpc call.
I am using dagger for DI & I have been getting exceptions whenever I try to build my ManagedChannelBuilder inside the module method.

Code:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public AddressClient getAddressClient(){
 return new AddressClient(ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("host, "port").usePlaintext().build());
}
```

> Exception in thread "main"
> io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No
> functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on
> the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact web_1    |
> at
> io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:43)
> web_1    |    at
> io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)

And when I try to build the channel inside my class AddressClient(), the application starts seamlessly.

Note: I have seen some examples on SO but mostly the answers are to add corresponding dependencies. IMO this shouldn't  be a dependency issue as the app starts when I follow  Approach2 to built my ManagedChannel.

Comment: Strange. Are you running within a framework of some sort? Like, is your application in control of main() or is something else starting the process and then loading your application?

Comment: No, not using spring. I guess it is normal service with gradle as build system & main loads all the dependencies , starts app.
```App app = DaggerApi_App.builder()
                .build();
        Api api = app.api();```

Comment: This sort of issue is typically caused by ClassLoader magic going on. The likes of frameworks, servlets, OSGi. They can all be addressed if you know what is causing it... I'm particularly surprised that Dagger has trouble, since I thought it runs "in the application" from the perspective of the JVM.